# How to add a UTF8 arabic or farsi symbol to Texlive?

Tags: input-encodings, arabic, persian

the following MWE gives a error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,arabic]{babel}
\Novocalize
\begin{document}


بهخێربێن  

ترحيب
\end{document}
```

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ێ (U+6CE)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX. Any help?

Comment: (don't use `etex` package on recent latex releases) you can use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{06CE}{????}` where `????` is whatever you need it to be, I don't know if the character is in the fonts you are using, sorry I can not read Arabic.

Comment: Not me either, I want to write welcome in different languages and got stuck :(